# Quiz in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm quite new to programming and I have to recreate a quiz. Though something is not working properly, the biggest issue is: when selecting an answer I should get the message about whether the answer is correct or wrong(answers should be hidden, and the next button displayed) and after clicking the next button, answers get displayed again and the button hidden.

Here is my code:

```js
const questions = [
    {
        question: "Here's an easy one. Can you recognise this premium SUV?",
        image: "images/jaguar.jpg",
        answers: ["Jaguar E-Pace", "Porsche Cayenne", "Mercedex GLA"],
        correct: "Jaguar E-Pace"
    },
    {
        question: "Do you think you can recognise what BMW series this is?",
        image: "images/bmw8.jpg",
        answers: ["BMW 6 Series", "BMW 3 Series", "BMW 8 Series"],
        correct: "BMW 8 Series"
    },
    {
        question: "Time for another SUV...",
        image: "images/duster.jpg",
        answers: ["Dacia Duster", "MINI Countryman", "Jeep Renegade"],
        correct: "Dacia Duster"
    },
    {
        question: "Do you recognise this new saloon?",
        image: "images/genesis.jpg",
        answers: ["MG HS", "Genesis G80", "Audi A7"],
        correct: "Genesis G80"
    },
    {
        question: "Can you recognise this family SUV?",
        image: "images/outlander.jpg",
        answers: ["Hyundai Santa Fe", "Kia Sorento", "Mitsubishi Outlander PHEV"],
        correct: "Mitsubishi Outlander PHEV"
    },
    {
        question: "Now for a compact SUV...",
        image: "images/ford.jpg",
        answers: ["Ford Puma", "Porsche Macan", "Nissan Juke"],
        correct: "Ford Puma"
    },
    {
        question: "Can you guess what German hatchback this is?",
        image: "images/audi3.jpg",
        answers: ["Mercedes A Class", "Audi A3 Sportback", "Bmw 1 Series"],
        correct: "Audi A3 Sportback"
    },
    {
        question: "Hmmm, how about this one... ",
        image: "images/renault.jpg",
        answers: ["Renault Zoe", "DS 3", "Nissan Micra"],
        correct: "Renault Zoe"
    },
    {
        question: "Which Hyundai is this?",
        image: "images/hyundaikona.jpg",
        answers: ["Hyundai i10", "Hyundai Ioniq", "Hyundai Kona"],
        correct: "Hyundai Kona"
    }, 
    {
        question: "What hatchback is this?",
        image: "images/mazda2.jpg",
        answers: ["Ford Focus", "Mazda 2", "Nissan Micra"],
        correct: "Mazda 2"
    },
    {
        question: "Can you recognise this premium saloon?",
        image: "images/jaguarxe.jpg",
        answers: ["Jaguar XE", "BMW 3 Series", "Mercedes E Class"]
    },
    {
        question: "What SUV is this?",
        image: "images/jeep.jpg",
        answers: ["Landrover Discovery", "Jeep Compass", "Kia Sorento"],
        correct: "Jeep Compass"
    },
    {
        question: "What Ford model is this?",
        image: "images/fiesta.jpg",
        answers: ["Puma", "Kuga", "Fiesta ST"],
        correct: "Fiesta ST"
    },
    {
        question: "Do you recognise this Maserati?",
        image: "images/maserati.jpg",
        answers: ["Ghibli", "Levante", "Quattroporte"],
        correct: "Ghibli"
    },
    {
        question: "Can you guess what Landrover this is?",
        image: "images/rangerover.jpg",
        answers: ["Range Rover", "Evoque", "Defender"],
        correct: "Range Rover"
    },
    {
        question: "What new Hybrid super mini this is?",
        image: "images/fiat.jpg",
        answers: ["MINI Hatchback", "Fiat 500", "Renault Twingo"],
        correct: "Fiat 500"
    },
    {
        question: "How about this Skoda model?",
        image: "images/skoda.jpg",
        answers: ["Octavia", "Kamiq", "Superb"],
        correct: "Octavia"
    },
    {
        question: "Can you recognise this Volvo?",
        image: "images/volvo.jpg",
        answers: ["XC40", "XC90", "XC60"],
        correct: "XC 40"
    },
    {
        question: "Which Volkswagen model is this?",
        image: "images/golf.jpg",
        answers: ["Arteon", "Golf", "T-Roc"],
        correct: "Golf"
    },
    {
        question: "What is this hatchback?",
        image: "images/corsa.jpg",
        answers: ["Vauxhall Corsa", "Vauxhall Astra", "Vauxhall Adam"],
        correct: "Vauxhall Corsa"
    }
]

const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionEl = document.getElementById('question')
const answers = document.getElementById('answers')
const message = document.getElementById('message')
const image = document.getElementById('image')
//const text = document.getElementById('text')

let questionNr = 0

startButton.addEventListener("click", startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    questionNr++
    setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame() {
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    question.classList.remove('hide')
    setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
    resetState()
    showQuestion(questions[questionNr])

}

function showQuestion(question) {
    questionEl.innerHTML = question.question
    //answers.innerHTML = questions[questionNr].answers
    image.src = questions[questionNr].image
    answers.innerHTML = ''
    questions[questionNr].answers.forEach(answer => {
        answers.innerHTML += `<button class="btn">${answer}</button>`
    })
        // question.answers.forEach(answer => {
        // const button = document.createElement('button')
        // button.innerText = `${answer}`
        // button.classList.add('btn')
        // if (answer.correct) {
        //     button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
        // }
        // button.addEventListener("click", selectAnswer)
        // answers.appendChild(button)

        const answerBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
    Array.from(answerBtns).forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (btn.textContent === questions[questionNr].correct) {

                message.style.display = 'flex'
                correct.style.display = 'flex'
                const stats = document.getElementById('stats')
                stats.innerHTML = `${questionNr + 1}/${questions.length}`
            } else {
                message.style.display = 'flex'
                wrong.style.display = 'flex'
                stats.innerHTML = `${questionNr + 1}/${questions.length}`
            }
            nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
           // answers.style.display = "none"

    });
})
}

function resetState() {
    nextButton.classList.add('hide')
    while (answers.firstChild) {
        answers.removeChild
        (answers.firstChild)
    }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
    const selectedButton = e.target
    const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
    setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
    Array.from(answers.children).forEach(button => {
        setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
    })
    if (questions.length > questionNr + 1) {
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
    } else {
        startButton.innerHTML = "Restart Quiz"
        startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
    clearStatusClass(element)
    if (correct) {
        element.classList.add('correct')
    } else {
        element.classList.add('wrong')
    }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
    element.classList.remove('correct')
    element.classList.remove('wrong')
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #081536;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#content {
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

#correct {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

#correct h1, p {
    color: white;
}

#wrong {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

#wrong h1, p {
    color: white;
}

#content img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#next, #next-wr {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

#answers {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.btn {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CarQuiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="message" class="hide">
            <div id="correct">
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <h1>Well done!</h1>
                <p id="correct-answer"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="wrong">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
                <h1>Wrong!</h1>
                <p id="actual-answer"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <img src="" alt="" id="image">
            <div class="text" class="hide">
                <div id="stats"></div>
                <div id="question" class="hide"></div>
                <div id="answers" class="hide">
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
                    <button id="next-btn" class="hide-btn btn">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most optimal way of achieving what you need (there would have to be some rewriting to what you have right now, and you can focus on that later on), but this is one way of solving it.

1. Add a `hide` class to your `next` button, so that it wouldn't be visible once the quiz is loaded.
2. In your `style.css`, add `!important` to your `.hide {...}`. I'll explain the reason for this later.
3. In your `setNextQuestion()` function declaration, add the following line:

```
message.classList.add('hide');
```

This is needed because you want to hide the message ("Well done!" / "Wrong!"), once the new questions are loaded. Since you're adding the inline `display:flex` to your `#message`, it has a greater specificity in comparison to what the `.hide` sets for the display. That's why adding `!important` was needed. Again, this is just the simplest way of solving it, and perhaps not the best.

4. In your `showQuestion(question)` function declaration, change this

```
answers.innerHTML += `<button class="btn">${answer}</button>`
```

to this

```
answers.innerHTML += `<button class="answer-btn btn">${answer}</button>
```

5. In the same function, change this

```
const answerBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
```

to this

```
const answerBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('answer-btn')
```

The reason - `.btn` class is also used elsewhere (`start`,`next`), and, presumably, you don't want to collect those buttons as well as those related to the answers.

6. Below the previous line of code, add this

```
answers.classList.remove('hide');
```

This line is needed, because of what we did in step 2. The importance of `.hide` has been increased, and without this line, our questions would not be showing up.

7. Also in the same function declaration, when attaching the click event listeners to individual `answerBtns`, you need to make the following changes (the ones with the `// new` are what you need to add):

```
Array.from(answerBtns).forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        message.classList.remove('hide'); // new
        answers.classList.add('hide'); // new
        if (btn.textContent === questions[questionNr].correct) {
            message.style.display = 'flex'
            correct.style.display = 'flex'
            wrong.style.display = 'none'; // new
            const stats = document.getElementById('stats')
            stats.innerHTML = `${questionNr + 1}/${questions.length}`
        } else {
            message.style.display = 'flex'
            wrong.style.display = 'flex'
            correct.style.display = 'none'; // new
            stats.innerHTML = `${questionNr + 1}/${questions.length}`
        }
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
       // answers.style.display = "none"

    });
})
```

The reason for adding these - regardless of whether the answer is correct or not, we need to hide the questions and show the answer holder (`message`). Then, within the if / else, we show the appropriate message (correct / incorrect), and hide the other (incorrect / correct).

---

Some notes:

- while this will do what you intend ( *(answers should be hidden, and next button displayed) and after clicking next button, answers get displayed again and the button hidden*), it won't solve the issue with the quiz not displaying the end result / score, once it's done
- once the last question has been answered, clicking on the `next` button will trigger a console error, since there are no more questions within your `const questions`. You can solve this by introducing a simple check right after the `showQuestion(question)` function is initialized. For example:

```
function showQuestion(question) {
    if(typeof question.question === 'undefined') {
        return false; // additionally, do something else - alert the user, show the score,etc
    }

    // ... the rest of your original code
}
```